# AdWords Track Multiple Click Conversions Separately

Tags: google-ads-api

I can't find any up to date documentation on this scenario, and it's really frustrating.

I have tel:555-555-5555 links and mailto:johndoe@555.com and I want to track each click separately.

Should I add two of these snippets, one for each type?  I noticed there is a "Conversion_Label" field, so I assume I should?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
goog_snippet_vars = function() {
var w = window;
w.google_conversion_id = XXXXXXXXX;
w.google_conversion_label = "XXX1";
w.google_remarketing_only = false;
}
// DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
goog_snippet_vars();
window.google_conversion_format = "3";
window.google_is_call = true;
var opt = new Object();
opt.onload_callback = function() {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
  window.location = url;
}
}
var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
conv_handler(opt);
}
}
/* ]]> */
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

From here, now Google just says to add the onClick handlers but they are the same other than the link inside:

```
<a onclick="goog_report_conversion
    ('http://www.example.com/whitepapers/a.pdf')"
    href="#" >DOWNLOAD NOW</a>
<a onclick="goog_report_conversion
    ('tel:555-555-5555')"
    href="#" >CALL NOW</a>
```

Will Google tell the difference between the two click events?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

No, there will be no difference between the two click events.

This is my workaround:

1. Setup one additional conversion code (for the download conversion). The difference from the first conversion code will be only in this line w.google_conversion_label = "XXX2";
2. Next change the line of the new code from  ***goog_snippet_vars = function() {*** to ***goog_snippet_varsD = function() {***
3. Next change the line of the new code from ***goog_report_conversion = function(url) {*** to ***goog_report_conversionD = function(url) {***. Don't mind the warning   // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW. :)
4. Next change the line of the new code from ***goog_snippet_vars();*** to ***goog_snippet_varsD();*** Don't mind the warning   // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW. :)
5. Last change - from:

`<a onclick="goog_report_conversion
    ('http://www.example.com/whitepapers/a.pdf')"
    href="#" >DOWNLOAD NOW</a>`

to

`<a onclick="goog_report_conversionD
    ('http://www.example.com/whitepapers/a.pdf')"
    href="#" >DOWNLOAD NOW</a>`

Voila! Now you are ready to track two conversion actions in one page.

Comment: any links or documentation to back that up?